# VSTS Build and Release definition: Could both build and release definition use the same agent or each must use different agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm currently creating a release definition for our project and I'm stuck with this problem, **could both build and release definition use the same agent** if yes, then how? If no, what are other options to do this?

I've already posted the same question on github and Microsoft developer community. Here are the links:

Microsoft Dev:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108045/could-both-build-and-release-definition-use-the-sa.html#

Github:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Set agent for release:

[image]

Set default agent for build (You can change agent when queue build)

[image]

An article about setup a private agent: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only question I have now is regarding the deployment groups. Do I still need to register my machine by running the power shell script under the Deployment Groups tab in VSTS (this process seems to register a new agent which causes an error because there's already an existing one)?

Comment: @Lorenz Yes, you would need to register the agent again using a different name for the deployment group.

Comment: @Lorenz If you need to use Deployment group phase in release, you need to register a new agent (can in the same machine) for the deployment groups, otherwise no (There is Deployment group phase in the screenshot, you can ignore it). Regarding register a new agent with PowerShell, by default, it uses this command to register agent: .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://starain.visualstudio.com/'  --projectname 'Scrum2015' --deploymentgroupname "DeployG1" ; Remove-Item $agentZip;, You can modify argument before register agent.

Comment: @Harshil Lodhi Okay. I'll try.

Comment: @HarshilLodhi How can I use the same agent I created for the deployment group phase?

Comment: @Lorenz No, you can't, the agents of deployment group can't be used for build and release agent phase.

Comment: @HarshilLodhi Okay. So in this case I'll be needing 2 different agents, 1 for build and release definitions and 1 for the deployment group, do I get it right?

Comment: @HarshilLodhi But running the power shell script from the deployment group tab would just throw an error because it would just detect/use the same agent settings right?

Comment: @Lorenz By default, the agent for deployment group is in C:\vstsagent\A1 folder, you can download the agent to another folder [admin page=>Agent pools=>Download agent), then configure it as build/release agent or deployment group agent, also specify different agent name when configure.

Comment: @Lorenz Do you success configuring the build agent and deployment group?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Yes, I already got it working. Now I have 1 agent for build/release definition and 1 for the deployment group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both your build and release definitions can use the same set of agents ( which are called Agent Queues in VSTS )

For eg. - You can configure an agent in the "Default" agent queue in VSTS and configure both your build and release definitions to use "Default" queue. This will allow you to run both builds and releases but a single agent can only run any one of them at one point of time

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/pools-queues

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try it.